# Custom loss function optimized for correlation for gradient boosted trees algorithms like XGBRegressor or LGBMRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, loss-functions, gradient-descent, catboost

I have a rather classical tabular data prediction problem and more or less successfully using XGBRegressor or LGBMRegressor both using MSE as their loss function.

A slight deviation from the standard problem is that training data contains groups of rows (observations and target) belonging together (eras of data) and test data are coming as one out-of-the-sample era (matrix of feature data) and I am predicting the vector. Quality of my predictions is evaluated by correlation with true target.

I am wondering: would some of the standard loss/objective functions in GBM models provide a better correlation of predictions? Could there be a custom loss function based on correlation?

P.S. Actually my predictions are raised to the power of 1.5 to amplify top and bottom parts of my prediction vector.